# PHP extensions dir with YUM

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, yum, ec2-ami

I've installed PHP on a Linux machine but can't seem to find the 'modules' directory from PHP.
On Mac with MAMP installed, this folder is located in `~/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/`, but I can't figure out where this folder is installed on Linux, with `yum`.

Anyone who nows where yum installs these PHP-directory?

---

**Edit: some more information about the environment**

I'm working with Amazon EC2 on an Amazon Linux AMI (ami-1624987f).
But while developing, I've used Ubuntu and installed everything (Apache, PHP, MySQL) via `apt-get`.

The installation was done by `yum install php php-devel php-mysql`

Now, when moving the application to EC2, seems like apt is not available on this AMI and I have to use yum. Seems like the **yum** installation is different from **apt** because I can't find the folder as described above.

**Edit2: conclusion**

There were more issues so at the end I've switched from Amazon Linux to Ubuntu where I also could use apt-get. But the answer from chanthemanless works. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Open php.ini and look at the [`extension_dir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dir) setting.

Comment: it says `extension_dir = "/"`, does this means it's in the root of the disk?

Comment: That would appear to be what it is saying, yes - that doesn't seem right though.

Comment: "I've installed PHP..." How? "... on a Linux device..." Which?

Comment: Neither yum nor apt is responsible for where packages install their files.

Comment: I've launched the EC2-instance, ssh'ed into it and `yum install php` works out of the box. Does yum use a default installation directory?

Comment: Yes. yum uses `/` by default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run a:

```
sudo php -i | grep extension
```

The output should show something like:

extension_dir => /blah/blah/blah

Or you could run a:

```
sudo find / -name '*php*'
```

And look at all the places you have php files.

Answer (score 1):

I was using PHP 7.2.24 in Amazon EC2 instance , even though extensions were installed and i was not able to locate the path. By doing phpinfo() I found extension_dir was set to /usr/lib64/php/modules where all directories where installed.

I modified php.ini under /etc folder and still could not reflect. But later found this very useful link [Click here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=820299&tstart=0) where i found we need to restart php-fpm after doing the modification and later restart apache.

> sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service

I hope it helps someone.